# Make batch code to connect to server and stop services

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I wanted to know if there is a way to make a batch file to conncet to multiple servers and stop certain services from where you run the bat file? Thanks!

Comment: What servers do you mean? What Operating Systems do they run?

Comment: Sorry, windows server 2003. One is phisycal server and the other 4 are Virtual ones. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
@echo off
setlocal  enabledelayedexpansion

for %%a (SRV-01,SRV-02,SRV-03) do (
    set srv=
    set srv=%%a
    net use \!srv! /USER:domain\user password       
    sc \\!srv! stop'service-name'
)

exit
```

SRV-01/02/03 etc.. can be also IP address or just by name.

Comment: beutiful! thanks so much. So then if I just want to restart them I would have to run pretty much the same code after a while but with the "start" command..correct?

Comment: I have tried this but does not seem to work unless am doing something wrong. :)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having to use a for loop

```
wmic service where "name='WerSvc'" call startservice
```

The wmic command can take a text file of ip addresses or computernames

```
127.0.0.1
serenity
```

to specify a computer

```
wmic /node:127.0.0.1 service where "name='WerSvc'" call startservice
```

or in a file (@ says it's a filename)

```
wmic /node:@computerlist.txt service where "name='WerSvc'" call startservice
```

Comment: When running this my PC shows an error of "Access Denied". Thanks!